# How to update coordinates in a geodatabase with FME?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form

I have an excel file of points which are resurveyed with updated Coordinates.Now I want to update my existing arcsde geodatabase. How can i update only coordinates in FME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GEODB reader, Excel reader, featuremerger (objectid), VertexCreator (replace point), GEODB writer (update, objectid).

---

The SDE writer can create new tables but also, insert rows and update rows. I'm by no means an SDE export but I think OBJECTID is the unique ID created by SDE. This way only the rows that are merged with excel will get a new coordinate and only updated rows will be sent back to writer. With no attributes changed it will update the row with the same values and new geometry.

I would create a copy of the table in SDE for test, add table sde reader, duplicate on writer, AttributeExposer to get OBJECTID, AttributeKeeper to keep only OBJECTID, duplicate on sde writer, strip all attributes, set writer mode to update, set writer key to OBJECTID.

---

I built an example with the GDB API in FME 2016. The writer differs but the basics are the same:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36253197/update_point.zip

[image]

Comment: As its an sde database and other applications are using it so i cant add XY in database schema.I need to update geometry

Comment: i have followed your steps and working fine up till vertex creator where i have selected the option replace with point and given the Coordinates X and Y from my excel sheet.when i am going for writer mode and giving only OBJECT ID to update errors appear "NULL pointer check failed.   File: geodbfeatureclass.cpp   Line #: 1010
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
"

Comment: I will try to reproduce you error. What version of FME Desktop and what exact writer do you use?

Comment: FME version 2015.1.1.0 Win 64

Writer Mode ->   Update
Geometry->           geodb_point 
Update key field->         OBJECTID

Comment: Sounds OK to me. Can you share your workbench or printscreen writer parameters? Found only one hit on your errorlog. https://geonet.esri.com/thread/161845 where it seems they solved it but not stating how exactly... "It turned out I was not implementing the FMEobjects API properly."

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind effort.i am using old version of FME so unable to open workspace

Comment: Thank you very much it worked.still dont know what was the error just opened a new work space and it runs fine.Now i will try on my SDE database.Once again thank you for your kind support and help.Much appreciated